# JQuery scroll to anchor acting odd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i've got a script to scroll to an anchor on click. It doesnt seem to work on the "first" click going down. it will jump, rather than scroll. but after the first click, it jumps to the anchor and my menu appears, and then all the links (including the first one that jumped) work fine. im not sure what would cause this, and was wondering if anyone else would have an idea?

I have a JSFiddle, but it works fine there. only when i implement the same code into my site is when it happens.

Thanks

http://spo.comxa.com/

uploaded the files above for testing, same thing is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/reeceheslop/b59fn43e/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;

    });
});
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to debug a problem without seeing an example of it. Have you checked the console for errors? Do you have elements with duplicate ids in the page which is causing unexpected behaviour for `$target.offset().top`?

Comment: added a link to the original post that is hosting the files

Comment: You have a plugin added to this page? `nice` something? It's not added to the `jsFiddle` though.

Comment: nicescroll, it's a plugin to change the scroll speeds and scrollbar... etc. i tried it with that removed and the same thing occurs. so i assumed it was not affecting it... the nicescroll plugin should be viewable on the source code of the upload.

Answer (score 2):

Your click function seems to be nested inside of a scroll event listener, so I assume its not being called until something is scrolled. Try moving it to the outside along with the document ready function like this:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var newPos = (window.scrollY * -1) / 5
    document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundPosition = "center " + newPos + "px";

var startY = 300;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
});

function checkY(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
        $('.fixednav').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.fixednav').slideUp();
    }
}


checkY();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;

    });
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i had tried your suggestion earlier and it stopped scrolling all together, so i moved it back, i thought it was odd that it would work when inside the scroll event listener. i'll keep fiddling with that, it may have something to do with the issue.

Comment: @ReeceHeslop you need to include the *js.js* file **after** including the *jquery* library (*since your script uses jquery*)

Comment: That is very valid, and i had not thought of that. But even after including it after the JQuery, i am still having the same issue. This issue is just annoying me now, because i just cant figure it out! Thanks for your comment. appreciate it

Comment: i think it definitely has something to do with the scroll event listener, after i just noticed that if i scroll, even just once, after loading, it works fine. It may be a matter of starting from scratch and tidying up my scripts and writing them in the order they need to be called. because i wrote them kind of as i was thinking of ideas, which could have led to the issue.